# Website working in Chrome, Firefox but no in Safari

Tags: html

I'm building a test website (http://rocketplays.com), it's working on Chrome and Firefox but when I try to open the website in Safari it's locked in the bottom part of the website. Any clue what would work to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to cause the issue in Safari:

```
.main-content {
   flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

Try adding this to the bottom of your css file:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    .main-content {
        flex: 1;
    }
}
```

or I believe the conditional may not be necessary and you can change

```
.main-content {
   flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

to

```
.main-content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have detected the file that causes the issue and this is one of the stylesheets: [**thesaas.min.css**](http://rocketplays.com/assets/css/thesaas.min.css).

After running a test of your CSS code, it appears that the CSS code is not compatible with the following browsers: **IE 8-11**, **Safari 8**, **Internet Explorer Mobile 11** and **iOS Safari 8**.

I would recommend you to **[click this link](https://www.browseemall.com/)**, copy paste **[your CSS code](http://rocketplays.com/assets/css/thesaas.min.css)** and once the analysis is completed, click on '**Safari 8**' tab to see what lines are causing the issues.

Let me know if you have any further questions.